# prove that $F$ is a closed set and $p(F)$ is not closed

Tags: functional-analysis

Take a projection $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ which is given by $p(x,y)=x$. So, if you choose the closed set $F=\{(x,y)\mid xy=1\}$ then $p(F)$ is not closed.

why $F$ is closed and why $p(F)$ is not close?

Comment: The image of a closed set by a continuous map need not be closed

Comment: Yeah i know, but i need to prove that

Comment: Well, you only have to prove $\mathbf R^*$ is not closed. For instance you can prove its complement $\{0\}$ is not an open set. Or you can prove it is not sequentially closed. It's not hard to find a sequence of non-zero real numbers that converges to $0$.

Comment: Is this tag suitable for this question?

Comment: I guess $p (F) = \left( -\infty,0 \right) \cup \left( 0, +\infty \right)$, which isn't closed.

Comment: For the first side of the question, assuming you're in a metric space, i would just take a convergent sequence of $F $ and just show that the limit belongs to $F $ as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- $F$ is closed since it is the pre-image of a continuous map. The continuous map considered here is $f(x,y) = xy$
- Notice that $(\frac 1 n, n) \in F$ for every $n \in \Bbb N$. So $\dfrac 1 n \in p(F)$ for every $n \in \Bbb N$. But $\dfrac 1 n \to0$ and $0$ is not in $p(F)$. Hence, $p(F)$ is not closed.

Comment: can you explain little more why $F$ is closed?

Comment: One important definition for a continuous function between two metric spaces is: "A function $f: X \to Y$  is continuous if $f^{-1}(A)$ is open in $X$ for any open set $A$ of $Y$". An equivalent condition is: "A function $f: X \to Y$  is continuous if $f^{-1(}A)$ is closed in $X$ for any closed set $A$ of $Y$". Our $X$ is $\Bbb R^2$, $Y$ is $\Bbb R$ and $f$ is taken to be the map $(x, y) \mapsto xy$. $A$ is $\{1\}$.

Answer (score 1):

$F$ is closed because is the inverse image of a closet set (what closed set?) by a continuous function (what continuous function?).

The image set is
$$p(F) = \Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$$
because...

Comment: I still haven't understand why F is closed